# Add a button/html content to kendo dialog title bar

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui

I want to add a button with some text positioned left to the close button in the kendo dialog as per a given design.

I have tried by adding a button in the dialog body then move it with relative position, button moved but it's getting hidden under the title bar.
I have checked and manipulated the css of close button and dialog title but could not make the button visible when the header is visible.

Can any one help on how it can be done?

I have created a dojo in below link, you can check it.

https://dojo.telerik.com/osotAwAy

Comment: Include some code *here*.

Comment: @AndyHoffman - I have added the dojo link https://dojo.telerik.com/osotAwAy in the question, did you check it

Comment: All right, I can work with this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the safe way to approach it—to make the title bar a relative container and position the button absolutely within that relative container.

First, append the `button` into the titlebar.

```
$(".k-dialog-titlebar").append(
  '<button id="btnMoveMe">Move Me</button>'
)
```

Then, add the following `CSS`:

```css
#btnMoveMe {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  right: 30px;
  top: 12px;
  position: absolute;
}
.k-dialog-titlebar {
  position: relative;
}
```

[Demo link](https://dojo.telerik.com/osotAwAy/2)

Answer (score 0):

Apply `overflow:visible` to `.k-prompt-container, .k-window-content`:

```
.k-prompt-container, .k-window-content{overflow:visible}
```

And modify `#btnMoveMe` class:

```
#btnMoveMe {
background-color: blue;
color: white;
position: absolute;
right: 30px;
top: -41px;
```

}

**[Check here](https://dojo.telerik.com/osotAwAy/3)**

Comment: Thanks, this does what i was looking for but I have chosen the solution by @andy for the better approach to append the button to title bar